# text Input layout for edittexts created programmatically

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-textinputlayout

I have created edittexts programmatically in android activity.java file. I want to add the textinputlayout for the edittexts. Is there any way to do that. I have wrapped the edittext in the xml file . I wish to do the same for the edittexts created programmatically.

thanks in advance.

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {


      EditText emailText;
      EditText passText;
      Button loginButton;
      TextView registerView;
      int counter=0;


    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        emailText  = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.emailText);
        passText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
        loginButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.LoginButton);
        registerView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.RegisterView);



        final TextInputLayout nameText = new TextInputLayout(getActivity());
        final TextInputLayout DeptText = new TextInputLayout(getActivity());
        final EditText phoneNumber = new EditText(getActivity());
        final Button registerButton = new Button(getActivity());
        final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.fragmentLayout);
        phoneNumber.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parameters1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) ;
        nameText.setLayoutParams(parameters1);
        DeptText.setLayoutParams(parameters1);
        phoneNumber.setLayoutParams(parameters1);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parameters2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) ;
        parameters2.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        registerButton.setLayoutParams(parameters2);
        nameText.setHint("Enter Name");
        DeptText.setHint("Enter Department");
        phoneNumber.setHint("Enter Phone Number");
        registerButton.setText("Register");
        registerView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        registerView.setTextSize(17);



        registerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                counter++;
                if(counter==1) {
                    layout.addView(nameText,1 );
                    layout.addView(DeptText, 2);
                    layout.addView(phoneNumber,3);
                    layout.removeView(loginButton);
                    layout.addView(registerButton,5);
                    registerView.setText("Already signed Up? login");
                }
                else{
                    layout.removeView(nameText);
                    layout.removeView(DeptText);
                    layout.removeView(phoneNumber);
                    layout.removeView(registerButton);
                    layout.addView(loginButton,2);
                    registerView.setText("New User? Sign Up");
                    counter=0;

                }


            }
        });
     return view;
    }


}
```

Comment: Off the cuff, create an instance of `TextInputLayout`, then call `addView()` on it to add the `EditText`.

Comment: tried. it is not working. the edit texts do not show up on running

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.

Comment: "I wish to do the same for the edittexts created programmatically" -- you are only creating one `EditText` programmatically (`phoneNumber`). You are not calling `addView()` on a `TextInputLayout`, passing in `phoneNumber`. Your other `EditText` widgets are coming from the inflated layout resource; put your `TextInputLayout` wrappers for those in the same layout resource.

Comment: I am trying hard but failing to understand. Can you give an example for clarification.thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

You can inflate layout from XML file like this:

Create text_input_layout.xml in your Layout res

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:hint="change hint"
        android:id="@+id/text_input_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

then inflate this in your code

```
TextInputLayout txtInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.text_input_layout,null);
TextInputEditText txtInputEditText = (TextInputEditText) txtInputLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_input_edit_text);
mRoot.addView(txtInputLayout);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try thinking of the TextInputLayout as a wrapper for EditText fields, for example:

```
    LinearLayout assessmentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.assessmentsLayout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    assert assessmentLayout != null;

    TextView screenTitle = new TextView(this);
    screenTitle.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    screenTitle.setText(String.format("Assessment: %s", course.getName()));
    assessmentLayout.addView(screenTitle);

    TextInputLayout titleWrapper = new TextInputLayout(this);
    titleWrapper.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    titleWrapper.setHint("Assessment Title:");
    assessmentLayout.addView(titleWrapper);

    title = new EditText(this);
    title.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    title.setText(assessment.getTitle());
    titleWrapper.addView(title);

    TextInputLayout descriptionWrapper = new TextInputLayout(this);
    descriptionWrapper.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    descriptionWrapper.setHint("Description:");
    assessmentLayout.addView(descriptionWrapper);

    description = new EditText(this);
    description.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    description.setText(assessment.getDescription());
    descriptionWrapper.addView(description);
```

You add the EditText views to the TextInputLayout wrappers instead of directly to the activity layout.